# How can I make it print ace for 1, jack for 11, queen for 12 and king for 13 while playing the game

Tags: python, random, blackjack

How can I make it print ace instead of 1, jack instead of 11, queen instead of 12 and king instead of 13, while playing the game, with the python program still working properly.

Is there a way I can do this without changing too much.

This is my code:

```
import random 

dealer_cards = []
player_cards = []

while len(dealer_cards) != 2:
    dealer_cards.append(random.randint(1, 13))
    if len(dealer_cards) == 2:
        print('The dealer has a hidden card and', dealer_cards[1])

while len(player_cards) != 2:
    player_cards.append(random.randint(1, 11))
    if len(player_cards) == 2:
        print('You have the cards,', player_cards)

if sum(dealer_cards) == 21:
    print('The dealer has the cards,', dealer_cards)
    print('The dealer has won because he has 21!')
    exit()

if sum(player_cards) == 21 and sum(dealer_cards) == 21:
    print('draw')
    exit()

elif sum(dealer_cards) > 21:
    print('The dealer has the cards,', dealer_cards)
    print('The dealer has bust because he has over 21!')
    exit()

while sum(player_cards) < 21:
    choice = str(input('Choose twist or stick? '))
    if choice == 'twist':
        player_cards.append(random.randint(1, 11))
        print('You now have the cards,', player_cards)
    else:
        print('The dealer has the cards,', dealer_cards)
        print('You have the cards,', player_cards)
        if sum(dealer_cards) > sum(player_cards):
            print('The dealer has won!')
            break
        else:
            print('You have won!')
            break

if sum(player_cards) > 21:
    print('You have bust because you are over 21!')

elif sum(player_cards) == 21:
    print('You have won because you have 21')
```

Comment: Hard-code a dict that maps integer values to the string you want printed for each.  See other card-game installations if you need specific details.  {1:"ace", 11:"jack", ...}

Comment: Have you considered making a `Card` class with a `__str__` method?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a dict of names and use it to extract the name:

```
card_names = {
   1: 'Ace',
   11: 'Jack',
   12: 'Queen',
   13: 'King',
}

>>> n = 12
>>> print(card_names.get(n, n))
Queen
```

The second parameter to `get` makes sure that if a number is not found in the dict it is printed as it is.

Now, your code is printing lists, that makes it more complex. You have to query that dict for each element of the list.

Your code:

```
print('You now have the cards,', player_cards)
```

Becomes:

```
print('You now have the cards: ', 
    ', '.join(str(card_names.get(c, c)) for c in player_cards))
```

That will iterate over the cards and query the dict one by one. Do that every time you're printing a list and it will work.

Since you have to repeat that snippet every time you're printing a list, you can create a function to avoid repetition:

```
def format_card_list(card_list):
    return ', '.join(str(card_names.get(c, c)) for c in card_list))
```

Then use it in your code:

```
print('You now have the cards: ', format_card_list(player_cards))
...
print('The dealer has the cards,', format_card_list(dealer_cards))
...
```

etc

Comment: Thanks, I’ll try it.